# How to tell if a string has been passed through htmlentities in PHP? And it needs html_entity_decode?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

We save data in our DB after passing it via `htmlentities` method to avoid any injection attacks

And while using it back, we do `html_entity_decode` to get back the original value. In some cases in our code, the `htmlentities` is done 2-3 times on the same peice of data due to our saving techniques (hard to explain). So we basically want to avoid encoding the same strings multiple times.

Is there a good reliable way to detect if a string has been passed via `htmlentities` method already?

I guess one way is to check for stuff like `&quot;` in the ecoded string, but anything more reliable? Any in built method that just tells me if a string is encoded or not?

We are using Laravel, maybe a helper method in there that could help us?

Comment: If you're using Blade templates with Laravel, you don't need to worry about this. You can simply use `{{ $var }}` [which will runs `htmlspecialchars()` when being displayed](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/blade#displaying-data). There's no need to worry about encoding/decoding throughout your app. Laravel also has [built in handling](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/queries#introduction) to prevent SQL injection, etc.

Comment: `htmlentities` **before** saving to the DB to avoid injection attacks is not a good idea - why not use the common ways for this instead?

Comment: @KirkBeard I'd say that comment should be an answer :-)

Comment: @ADyson Good point, I was being lazy... I've just posted an answer instead.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is fundamentally the wrong approach IMO. Store the data raw, as it comes. While it's in the database it can't do you any harm.

Pass it through `htmlentities` only when you're just about to put it into a HTML document - because that's the only context in which it could be dangerous.

That will save all the encoding and decoding - you simply encode it on demand as necessary.

Comment: What about SQL injection attacks? Raw data won't be a problem?

Comment: How do your queries look like? `htmlentities` won't resolve any common SQL injection attacks, as backticks are not affected

Comment: @Rohan – Same rule applies: Apply appropriate escaping  (so not HTML escaping since it is SQL not HTML) at the point you insert the strings into the SQL query (except you almost always should be using prepared statements and placeholders instead of escaping and string concatenation/interpolation)

Comment: @Rohan htmlentities has nothing to do with preventing SQL injection. As the others have mentioned, you would take the same approach to that risk, but using the appropriate tools for that job - i.e. using prepared statements and parameters to build and execute the query. As KirkBeard has pointed out though elsewhere on this page, Laravel has tools for dealing with these issues built-in so if you're using those correctly there shouldn't really be any need to worry about either script or SQL injection, the framework takes care of it for you, in normal usage

Comment: I see, this a legacy codebase, so this is how it was done, I will try to change it to prepared statements like everyone is suggestign to make it better

Answer (score 2):

As mentioned by ADyson, you're handling the data incorrectly throughout your system.

Laravel's templating engine "Blade" will automatically send your variables through `htmlspecialchars()` to prevent XSS attacks.

From the [documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/blade#displaying-data):

> Blade `{{ }}` statements are automatically sent through PHP's `htmlspecialchars` function to prevent XSS attacks.

This will protect your site from potential XSS attacks, without you needing to encode/decode your data as you run `INSERT`/`SELECT` queries against your database.

Provided you're using Laravel's built-in DB Builder / Eloquent, your SQL queries are also [protected automatically](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/queries#introduction):

> The Laravel query builder uses PDO parameter binding to protect your application against SQL injection attacks. There is no need to clean strings being passed as bindings.

Comment: So I only need to worry about raw DB queries right? Eloquent will handle it otherwise?

Comment: Provided you're following the [documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/database#running-queries), and using parameter binding, it'll protect you from SQL injection, "Parameter binding provides protection against SQL injection."